# Catching variable passed to jQuery script inside for-loop

Tags: php, jquery, arrays, variables

Examine following code:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($){
    jQuery(myAjax.idinfo).change(function()
    {
        $value = $(this).val();
        jQuery.ajax({
            type : 'post',
            dataType : 'json',
            url : myAjax.ajaxurl,
            data : {
                action: 'getuser', 
                value: $value,
                //_nonce: myAjax.ajaxurl myAjax.nonce???????
            },

            complete: function(response){
                var parsed = JSON.parse(response.responseText)
                var arr = [];
                for(var x in parsed){ arr.push(parsed[x]);}
                for(var i = 1; i<= myAjax.fieldcount; i++)
                {
                    jQuery(myAjax.index + i).val(arr[i]);
                }
            }
        });

    });
});
```

Note that myAjax is passed from a php script, so everything is available through myAjax.
Now in the for loop I want to use myAjax.index1 and index2 etc. Now how can I increment the index? I have read about using arrays for this problem. But if I push everything from myAjax into an array, the array wouldn't be only filled with index1, index2 etc. but also other values, so this isn't what I'm looking for.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Resolved, I passed 2 arrays to the jQuery script, like this:

```
wp_localize_script('ffd_js_script', 'myAjax', array(
        'ajaxurl' => admin_url('admin-ajax.php'),
        'fieldcount' => $myoptionValue['fieldcount'],
        'idinfo' => $myoptionValue['idinfo'])
        );
    wp_localize_script('ffd_js_script', 'myIndexArray', $arguments);
```

In the jQuery I pushed everything into another array (not sure that this is necessary) and then I can iterate over the array, like this:

```
var indexArray = [];
                for(var y in myIndexArray){ indexArray.push(myIndexArray[y]);}
                for(var i = 0; i<= myAjax.fieldcount-1; i++)
                {
                    jQuery(indexArray[i]).val(arr[i+1]);
                }
```